# SwiftUI: Missing parameter in call -StateObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to access a class in my settings view

```
  struct SettingsView: View {
        @StateObject var stat = StatusBarController()

    .....}
```

But I'm getting an error for a missing parameter in StatusBarController()

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
>
> Insert '<#NSPopover#>'

StatusBarController Class

```
class StatusBarController: ObservableObject {
    private var statusBar: NSStatusBar
    private var popover: NSPopover
    private var eventMonitor: EventMonitor?
    private var content: ContentView?
    
    
    init(_ popover: NSPopover)
    {
        self.popover = popover
        statusBar = NSStatusBar.init()
      
        
        if let statusBarButton = statusItem.button {
        ........
        }
        
        eventMonitor = EventMonitor(mask: [.leftMouseDown, .rightMouseDown], handler: mouseEventHandler)
    }

.......}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use default constructor for `StateObject` initialisation then provide default popover in controller `init`, like

```
class StatusBarController: ObservableObject {
    private var statusBar: NSStatusBar
    private var popover: NSPopover
    private var eventMonitor: EventMonitor?
    private var content: ContentView?
    
    
    init(_ popover: NSPopover = NSPopover())     // << here !!
    {
...
```

alternate is to make it optional (and update every dependency correspondingly)